# I need compute (9173501*9173502*9173504)%9173503 in C#;

Tags: c#

I need compute `(9173501 * 9173502 * 9173504) % 9173503` in C#; result = 2 but C# can't compute it.
 If you have any idea please help me.

Comment: There is no detail in your question. Try using [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)?

Comment: Use [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).

Comment: Show us the code! Cheers.

Comment: I'm no math expert, but I wonder if the formula can be rewritten as: (9173501%9173503)*(9173502%9173503)*(9173504%9173503)

Comment: Why do you want to compute it if you know result? :D

Comment: Thanx very very much :))Big integer is work, thanx

Comment: Is this for a test or something?

Comment: @the_lotus - Dude, you do realize that 9173501%9173503 == 9173501 ? The modulus does nothing. In general, mod(a,b) = a if a < b for positive a.

Comment: @MemmedNesrullayev: If your question has been answered, please accept an answer.

Comment: I'm puzzeled to why this question has been downvoted 6 times.  Any downvoters care to state your case?

Comment: @woodchips you are right, IVlad explained well what I was missing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert your number to a BigInteger before you begin computations:

```
Console.WriteLine((new BigInteger(9173501)*9173502*9173504)%9173503);
// Output: 2
```

Answer (score 47):

There is no need to use big integers.

Use this formula:

```
(x * y) % k = ((x % k) * (y % k)) % k
```

This way, you can apply the modulo to a product of two numbers, each of which will be `< 9173503`, so this product will fit in a `long`.

**Note:** the same holds true for addition:

```
(x + y) % k = ((x % k) + (y % k)) % k
```

And subtraction, with a slight change:

```
(x - y) % k = ((((x % k + k) % k) - ((y % k + k) % k)) % k + k) % k
```

It does not, however, hold for division:

```
(4 / 2) % 3 = 2
4 mod 3 = 1
2 mod 3 = 2
1 / 2 != 2
```

Comment: +1 Or looking at numbers maybe even simple ((k-2)*(k-1)*(k+1))%k = (-2)*(-1)*1 = 2... no need to use any computations

Comment: Nice Play with math +1

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - but why use intelligence when a computer can do it for you? :) I think some people have lost the ability to think at times.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov might I assume you got your education outside of the USA? I thought the same thing when I saw these numbers, but you beat me by three months... That is the correct solution, no doubt in my mind!

Answer (score 5):

You can't *directly* compute it without `BigInteger`, but *mathematically* it's equivalent to:

```
((long)9173501 % 9173503) * (9173502 % 9173503) * (9173504 % 9173503)  % 9173503
```

Comment: You can do it without `BigInteger`. You only need a `long`.

Comment: @IVlad, I thought the same, but `var result = (x * y * z) % m;` results in `-6942781` when `x`, `y`, `z`, and `m` are `long`s.

Comment: @Khan - in general, of course. For this problem, it shouldn't as long as you take the mod every two multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

This is a math question, not a programming one.

As you see the numbers are really close to each other, so substituting `n = 9173503` you will get: `(n-2)(n-1)(n+1) % n`.

Opening up the parenthesis you will get the following polynomial: `n^3 - 2*n^2 - n + 2` and the remainder by `n` will be:

- 2 for every n > 2
- 0 for n = 1, 2

This means that not only `(9173501 * 9173502 * 9173504) % 9173503 = 2`, but also `13^127^61 * (13^127^61 + 1) * (13^127^61 + 3) % (13^127^61 + 2)` is also `2`, which is most probably can not be calculated with C# or other programming languages.

Comment: Best use of algebra out of all the answers!