# What are some basic modulo arithmetic rules?

Tags: modulo

Let a = 10^18 and b = 10 ^ 18. c = 1 to 100000

I want to find ( a + b ) % c or ( a * b ) % c

I need to prevent integer overflow. How can I do so?

Comment: In C++? Implementing my own Big Integer class? There are some rules mentioned here :
`http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=642253&start=0&mc=10#1110284`
But, I am unable to understand which is correct and which is not

Comment: `(a * b) % c == ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`. You can find a more thorough list here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 (x * y) % k = ((x % k) * (y % k)) % k

 (x + y) % k = ((x % k) + (y % k)) % k

 (x - y) % k = ((((x % k + k) % k) - ((y % k + k) % k)) % k + k) % k
```

[I need compute (9173501*9173502*9173504)%9173503 in C#;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035848/i-need-compute-9173501917350291735049173503-in-c/19035982#19035982)